# How to update an Entity in CRM with a related Entity using a plug-in in CRM Dynamics 2013/2015

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2015

I am new to `CRM` and I am battling to update an entity using a Plugin, I have registered a plugin on the `PhoneCall` Entity pre-operation on create message, when I then query the regarding entity and write data from the regarding entity to my `PhoneCall` Entity, although I seem to get an error that the record with `GUID` xxxxx does not exist.

Here is my code below;

```
  public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
        }

        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));

        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            Entity phoneCallEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (phoneCallEntity.LogicalName != "phonecall")
                return;


            if (context.MessageName == "Create")
            {
                try
                {
                    QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression("new_zoiperhistorydata");
                    qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_regardingobjectid", "new_callduration");

                    var ZoiperData = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe);

                    if (ZoiperData != null && ZoiperData.Entities.Count > 0)
                    {

                        foreach (Entity entity in ZoiperData.Entities)
                        {
                            if (entity.Attributes.Contains("new_callduration"))
                                phoneCallEntity.Attributes["new_callduration"] = entity.Attributes["new_callduration"].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    service.Update(phoneCallEntity);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                    // Display the details of the inner exception.
                    if (ex.InnerException != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);

                        FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> fe = ex.InnerException
                            as FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>;
                        if (fe != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0}", fe.Detail.Timestamp);
                            Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", fe.Detail.ErrorCode);
                            Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", fe.Detail.Message);
                            Console.WriteLine("Trace: {0}", fe.Detail.TraceText);
                            Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                                null == fe.Detail.InnerFault ? "No Inner Fault" : "Has Inner Fault");
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
```

The code fails on the `service.Update(phoneCallEntity)`;

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you run your plugin in the **pre-operation** stage of the **Create** event. In deed is the phonecall not created in this stage (and has no Id) and you get the reported error message.
Actually you don´t have to update the phonecall by yourself using the **service.Update** method. Since the operation runs through you can just update the fields you like on the Target and let the CRM do the rest :)